# How to make a div proportionally fluid when scaling browser?

Tags: html, css, web, fluid-layout

So I want to make my content a 2 Column layout div that fills up the whole "container". But I want the "335px X 250px" div to be resized proportionally when window is scaled up or down. Here's a sample image of how I want it to look like the below image, how can I do this?

[image]

The JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/gdkvcnyj/15/

```
<body>
    <div id="body-wrap">
        <div id="mobilenav"></div>
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div id="container">
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>
                <div class="mix"></div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of Body Wrap -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have changed the `.mix` elements to use percentage widths instead of absolute values. [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/claytonF/gdkvcnyj/23/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: The thing is I want the width and height to scale proportionally. Not just the width.

Comment: Height is trickier than width. You could simply set the height property of the .mix elements to be a percentage, but this won't work in all browsers, plus if you add more content you will need to keep changing the value. I think the only option would be to use javascript. Have updated the jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/claytonF/gdkvcnyj/26/]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing set image sizes use percentages and the browser will adjust accordingly. Same with height.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `%` unit is proportional to the `div`'s container, not the viewport. Sounds like you want the viewport.

So, for sizing fully proportional to both width and *height* of the viewport, you want the viewport-relative units: `vw` and `vh`. Note that the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) is just recent, A-grade browsers, but if your use-case can handle it, they're the perfect way to go. Use them the same way you would the `%` unit, just knowing that they are relative not to the container, but rather to the window. So, if you wanted something to always be half the size of the window/viewport, sized on both axes:

```
height: 50vh;
width: 50vw;
```